# A project that implements a number of the design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, oop

Someone once mentioned to me about a project (or two), maybe written in Java, that they used in school to help teach them design patterns.  It implemented a number of the design patterns but was for learning purposes only.

I know you should not try to stuff a bunch of the design patterns into a application just for the sake of using them but I would like to see an example of them implemented in the context of a larger application.  So does anyone know of a code project\application that implements a number of design patterns (preferably in C#)?

Answer (score 1):

A nice example for the elegant application of design patterns is the *x*Unit test framework. Take the [Cook's Tour](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookstour/cookstour.htm) which explains the different patterns that were used. It's not a large application, but it is thoroughly documented and a good starting point to learn about patterns in practice.

Answer (score 0):

My school had us implement a project which was a Medical Image Viewer for MRI images.  I forgot a lot of the requirements, but they had to be able to show 1 or 4 images at a time.  There were parts of the project we didn't have to implement, like images could be readable from a remote device.  It had to be able to show JPG images.  I'm sorry I can't remember more of the requirements.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to link that.

Answer (score 0):

See the Java and C# applications in the Apache umbrella of projects. They certainly know their way around OOP.